# Disable possibility for user to click in RadioButton WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

To visualize digital inputs from a Model I use RadioButtons inside a ItemsControl to show if a digital input is set or not:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Inputs}" MinHeight="80">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{localization:LocalizationBinding LocalizationName, FallbackValue='Name unresolved'}" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The Model runs in a thread which updates the binded property.
But if the RadioButton is clicked with the Mouse there is also the built in event to set IsChecked to true which is then overwritten by the next update from the Model.

How can i override this click event, that the RadioButton does nothing when i click into it?

Comment: Set `IsEnabled` to false on your `RadioButton` ?

Comment: "runs in a thread which updates the binded property" - this sounds like a big no-no. You should only have one UI thread, and everything that updates the UI need to run on this UI thread.

Comment: The Update is done with Dispatcher.Invoke Method. So everything is fine here.
Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the `RadioButton` to `false`:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}"
             IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer IsHitTestVisible does provide a good way to prevent user interaction. But sometimes you see the click behavior e.g. the "clicking circle". 
Thanks for this proposal!

Comment: Try to set `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"` to get rid of the "clicking circle".

Answer (score 0):

You can disable a `RadioButton` item by setting its `IsEnabled` property to `False` as below. Note that setting the `IsHitTestVisible` property to `False` also disables items but it *does not make items grayed out*, which can confuse users.

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton Content="Option 1"
        IsChecked="True"
        Margin="7"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Option 2"
        Margin="7"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Option 3"
        Margin="7"
        IsEnabled="False"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The result is: (Note that Option 3 is both disabled and grayed out.)

[image]

Comment: The behavior behind HitTestVisible is what i need. because the radio buttons shall show the state of an input.

The button shall not be there that the user can click it.

Answer (score 0):

Binding the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and handle this event in code behind prevents the UI to show any clicking action

XAML:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Value}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="RadioButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"/>
```

CodeBehind:

```
private void RadioButton_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```